# ORACLE SQL mix tables with different key structure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables having the following structure. Table 1 has a key (ID,ASOFDATE), Table 2 has a key (ID). I would like to obtain a table say Table 3 with a key as Table 1. I am working with an ORACLE database. Is there a way to do this in an SQL?

I get it work for one asofdate however I do not know how to generalise it for all asofdate.

For one as of date:

```
select ID, VALUE, ASOFDATE, max(ASOFDATE) as NEW_ASOFDATE from (
select * from TABLE 1
where ASOFDATE = '09.03.2016'
union
select * from TABLE 2
where ASOFDATE <= '09.03.2016'
)
```

Here a concrete example of what I would like to do.

```
Table 1

ID  VALUE   ASOFDATE
1234    876 10.03.2016
2345    98  10.03.2016
3456    643 10.03.2016
1234    345 09.03.2016
2345    32  09.03.2016
3456    56  09.03.2016
1234    123 08.03.2016
2345    78  08.03.2016
3456    435 08.03.2016

Table 2

ID  VALUE   ASOFDATE
9876    961 10.03.2016
8765    467 09.03.2016
7654    234 08.03.2016
6543    56  07.03.2016
5432    7   06.03.2016

Table 3

ID  VALUE   ASOFDATE    NEW_ASOFDATE
1234    876 10.03.2016  10.03.2016
2345    98  10.03.2016  10.03.2016
3456    643 10.03.2016  10.03.2016
9876    961 10.03.2016  10.03.2016
8765    467 09.03.2016  10.03.2016
7654    234 08.03.2016  10.03.2016
6543    56  07.03.2016  10.03.2016
5432    7   06.03.2016  10.03.2016
1234    345 09.03.2016  09.03.2016
2345    32  09.03.2016  09.03.2016
3456    56  09.03.2016  09.03.2016
8765    467 09.03.2016  09.03.2016
7654    234 08.03.2016  09.03.2016
6543    56  07.03.2016  09.03.2016
5432    7   06.03.2016  09.03.2016
1234    123 08.03.2016  08.03.2016
2345    78  08.03.2016  08.03.2016
3456    435 08.03.2016  08.03.2016
7654    234 08.03.2016  08.03.2016
6543    56  07.03.2016  08.03.2016
5432    7   06.03.2016  08.03.2016
```

The entries of Table 2 get duplicated per each as of date in Table 1 however each time (per each as of date) only the entries in Table 2 satisfying the condition Table2.ASOFDATE <= TABLE1.ASOFDATE get into Table 3. Please follow in my example what happens to the entry in Table 2 with ID = 8765. It shows up in Table 3 two time. It does not appear when NEW_ASOFDATE is '08.03.2016'.

Comment: "I would like to obtain a table say Table 3 with a key as Table 1." What do you mean by this?

Comment: Add the expected result too.

Comment: Hi, take for example from Table 2 the ID 8765. It appears in Table 2 just one time. In Table 3 it appears so many times as long as Table2.ASOFDATE <= TABLE1.ASOFDATE (it does not appear in Table 3 when the NEW_ASOFDATE = '08.03.2016'). Thanks.

Comment: Table 3 is the expected result. In Table 3 the entries of Table 2 gets duplicated per each NEW_ASOFDATE as long as Table2.ASOFDATE <= TABLE1.ASOFDATE (see previous comment). Thanks.

Comment: and what did you try? so is not a coding service!

Comment: Hi. I get it working for one as of date but I do not know how to generalise it. I added the sql in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick I think

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT T2ID AS ID, T2VAL AS VAL, T2DATE AS DT, T1DATE AS MAXDT
        FROM 
        (
            -- WATCH OUT : Cartesian product !
            SELECT T1.ID as T1ID, T1.Value AS T1VAL, T1.ASOFDATE AS T1DATE, T2.ID AS T2ID, T2.Value AS T2VAL, T2.ASOFDATE AS T2DATE
            FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
        )

        UNION

        SELECT ID, VALUE AS VAL, ASOFDATE AS DT, ASOFDATE AS MAXDT FROM Table1
    )
    WHERE DT <= MAXDT
    ORDER BY MAXDT DESC , DT DESC, ID ASC
```

Note that I could not test it under Oracle as SQLfiddle Oracle is again broken
I tested it in Access and that works. I have adapted it for Oracle SQL but I could have omitted something,  so you might have to tweak it a litlle bit

Results:

```
ID          VAL DT          MAXDT
1234    876 10.03.2016  10.03.2016 
2345    98  10.03.2016  10.03.2016 
3456    643 10.03.2016  10.03.2016 
9876    961 10.03.2016  10.03.2016 
8765    467 09.03.2016  10.03.2016 
7654    234 08.03.2016  10.03.2016 
6543    56  07.03.2016  10.03.2016 
5432    7   06.03.2016  10.03.2016 
1234    345 09.03.2016  09.03.2016 
2345    32  09.03.2016  09.03.2016 
3456    56  09.03.2016  09.03.2016 
8765    467 09.03.2016  09.03.2016 
7654    234 08.03.2016  09.03.2016 
6543    56  07.03.2016  09.03.2016 
5432    7   06.03.2016  09.03.2016 
1234    123 08.03.2016  08.03.2016 
2345    78  08.03.2016  08.03.2016 
3456    435 08.03.2016  08.03.2016 
7654    234 08.03.2016  08.03.2016 
6543    56  07.03.2016  08.03.2016 
5432    7   06.03.2016  08.03.2016
```

**More important note:** 
It does a `CROSS JOIN` which will result in a cartesian product and so it is not suitable if you have huge tables

It was fun

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your feedback. To answer your questions: yes I did code it myself, no I don´t think I manged to clarify what I am trying to do. The entries of Table 2 get duplicated per each as of date in Table 1 however each time (per each as of date) only the entries in Table 2 satisfing the condition Table2.ASOFDATE <= TABLE1.ASOFDATE get into Table 3. Please follow in my example what happens to the entry in Table 2 with ID = 8765. It shows up in Table 3 two time. It does not appear when NEW_ASOFDATE is '08.03.2016'. I hope it clarifies.

Comment: ok this is much more clear now, I would advise to edit your question to add these explanations. I have a very vague idea on how to do it, without any guarantee of success, but it will require a cartesian product (CROSS JOIN). So this is not suitable if you have a high number of rows. COuld you give the number of rows in both tables approximately ?

Comment: Adapted it again and now it returns exactly what you want

Comment: Hi, Thomas. Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: NP, as I said, it was fun :) I just hope you dont have one million rows on each table or you will kill the server  or/and have some arguments with the DBAs hehe